# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parameters processing failed error in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, jboss

> 8:46:12,814 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ecmfi].[action]]
>   (http--192.168.192.38-8080-4) Servlet.service() for servlet action
>   threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parameters
>   processing failed.    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:407)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:428)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.handleQueryParameters(Parameters.java:183)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2811)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1333)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterNames(RequestFacade.java:379)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:459)
>   [struts.jar:1.2.9]    at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:816)
>   [struts.jar:1.2.9]    at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
>   [struts.jar:1.2.9]    at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>   [struts.jar:1.2.9]    at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
>   [struts.jar:1.2.9]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]

Comment: A very impressive exception

Answer (score 2):

I also got this exception with a JBoss / Spring application server.
It was due to one parameter appearing twice in the form (2 times the same path).
I would advise to make sure that all fields in the form and corresponding parameters in the submitted URL are valid.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today and discovered that it was due to an bad URL parameter. One of my parameters had no name and no value:

https://www.someurl.com?param1=A&param2=B&=&param3=c

Once I fixed the URL this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its a known issue for JBOSS AS-7.1.1.

Follow these threads

https://community.jboss.org/message/747210

[AS7-5143](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5143)

As of now, the only solution seems to be to downgrade to JBoss AS 7.1.0.